# What is the ‘art’ mentioned in: “Art is long, and time is fleeting”?

Tags: meaning-in-context, meaning, context

What does *art* refer to in the poem: *A Psalm of Life* by Henry Wadsworth Longfellow?

> **Art** is long and time is fleeting

My book says *Art* refers to the “art of living” but this doesn't convince me and I did not get any reasonable explanation on the Internet. The article on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Psalm_of_Life) doesn't mention anything on the meaning of *art*, instead it says the poem “is meant to inspire its readers to live actively, and neither to lament the past nor to take the future for granted.”

- What does *art* mean in this line?

> **Art** is long and time is fleeting
>   And our hearts though stout and brave.
>   Still like muffled drums are beating
>   Funeral marches to the grave

Comment: Some statues and urns and other pieces of art were created thousands of years ago, and still exist today. A number of them in perfect condition. They've lived millennia. The people who created them, all those thousands of years ago, are long dead, and lived 80 years at best. Art is long; life is short.

Comment: My question is with specific reference to the psalm of life

Comment: Ah, I see. Trouble is we don't do interpretation of poetry (or lyrics, literature, legalese, etc) here, because it's essentially moot: up to endless debate, which can never be settled with a single "definitive" answer. For more on what we can and can't answer here, please see the [help/on-topic].

Comment: @Dan Bron's interpretation is essentially correct, but in the context of the poem, "art" refers to both works of art in the narrow sense (painting, sculptures, etc.) and the art of "great men" who "leave their footprints on the sands of time". In the latter, broader, sense, "art" refers to the works and deeds of great people.

Comment: It's not about fine arts; it's about exercising any 'art' = craft or skill. Longfellow is paraphrasing Hippocrates, whose point was that the physician has only a short lifetime in which to develop and exercise his art.

Comment: @Silenus........ added the linee

Comment: The famous Latin phrase from which this is adapted is _ars longa, vita brevis_:  "Art is long; life is short."  The lifetime of works of art is being compared favorably with the lifetime of the artist.

Comment: The Greek word that Hippocrates used was _τέχνη_ 'tekhnê' (stress on final long ê). It's the source of English words like _technology, technical, technique, tectonic, architect_; it comes originally from the PIE root [*_teks-_](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/_/roots.aspx?type=Indo-European&root=teks-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Longfellow is alluding to an original line from Hippocrates, the father of medicine. The Greek is literally, "the art is long, life is brief". The art in question is medicine, and the sentiment of the original quote is that you never really live long enough to master your craft. 
The phrase is more popular in Latin translation [*ars longa, vita brevis*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ars_longa,_vita_brevis).

Comment: The [actual Greek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ars_longa,_vita_brevis) translates to "Life is short,
    the art long,
    opportunity fleeting,
    experimentation perilous,
    and judgement difficult."

Comment: The Greek and Latin versions are [available here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ars_longa,_vita_brevis#Translations).

Comment: +1 from me, I would never have known this but for your answer.